# imap count emails from certain emails

Tags: php, imap

as the title says i want to count how many emails i have got from a certain email.

```
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
```

this will not work as it counts all emails in the mail box. i want to make something that gives me emails from the filter email but if i have non it tells me it.

thanks in advance and i hope you can help.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense "how many emails i have got from a certain email." What do you want to filter on? Subject line, recipient, ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imap_search` will do a search on the currently-selected folder and return an array of matching messages.  If you're looking to match messages by their "From" header, you'll search using the `FROM` criterion.

So the size of the returned array should work for you:

```
count(imap_search($imap, 'FROM "' . $email . '"'))
```

Comment: (Forgive me any syntax blunders; I haven't coded php for years and years.)

Comment: @user633268: It may be related to the double-quotes.  Rather than passing the result from `imap_search` into `count`, look at the array returned by `imap_search` -- do its contents look correct?

Comment: @dkarp `$search = count(imap_search($imap, 'ALL'));
echo $search;` <-- that gives the correct number but the FROM does not... i will experiment..

Comment: @dkarp got half of it to work... but when the are no emails from that user it responds with 1 if it does have emails from that user it gives the correct number... can you think of anything.. i looked up the php page on it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php it says something about it returning 1 but i dont know how to fix it. thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @user633268: When there are no emails from the user, see what the result of `imap_search` is.  If it's not an `array`, you can put that test in your code and only call `count` if it is an array.

Comment: @dkarp when i echo it, it shows blank... im guessing its not an array

Answer (score 1):

`imap_search` confusingly returns `false` when there are no e-mails, and `count(false)==1`, so you actually need something like:

```
$response = imap_search($inbox,"FROM $sender");

$nEmails = 0;
if($response) {$nEmails  = count($response);}
```